# Some of my computers say 'PRO OA' on the OEM license sticker, others say 'PRO OA MEA', what's the difference

Tags: windows-7, licensing

In a nutshell, some of my Windows 7 machines say 'PRO OA' on the sticker, others say 'PRO OA MEA'.

What does this mean?

Comment: Is it possible that MEA means Middle-East and Africa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OA = OEM Activation

MEA = Middle East- Africa

APAC = Asia and Pacific

China = China